# How can I add the Version number AND Date to the footer of a document?

Tags: document-library, document, versioning

I've already figured out how to add the Version number using the method below:

https://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-display-sp-version-number-in-a-word-document/

However, I need to figure out what string I need to input into order to display both the document Version Number AND Date.

Currently =  Version {_UIVersionString} = Version 1.0

Goal = Version {_UIVersionString}, {????} = Version 1.0, 15/07/2019

Comment: Which date is that, today, last modified or created?

Comment: Last modified - the date of that particular version.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that simply uses the inbuilt Quickparts in Word instead.

The SharePoint label is simply set up to be the Version number. Then inside the word document the user will have to use the inbuilt {SaveDate} function, which pulls the most recent save date.

I've confirmed that this works with versioning, so that it doesn't get out of sync for users who can't see drafts.